# Relative bash colors that work with all schemes?

Tags: bash, colors

How can I have a "relative" color in bash, rather than hardcoded one? If I specify to use yellow "\033[93m" then it looks bad for those people that use white background.

Is there a way to specify not a color, but "style" so to speak? like "Highlight" or "Important" or "darken" or "Deprecated"?

Comment: My impression was that people who use a white background must be sure to set the representation of "yellow" to something that's readable for them. As the writer of the script you shouldn't care much about this.

Comment: What about _bold_, _underline_, _invert colors_ as different "markers"?

Comment: @mpy good call; I didn't think about those. Though "invert" is severely ugly, and bold and underline both convey "this is important". So no way to say "this is *not* important"

Comment: @slhck, maybe. But shifting blame doesn't make my script more friendly. If I can find a solution that works for everyone, I'd rather do that work upfront.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has nothing to do with this. The `bash(1)` man page contains no mention of color.

If your script is changing the text or background color, it's doing so by sending ANSI color escape codes, which are control-character bytes that `bash` just ignores and passes right through to your terminal emulator just like it sends any ASCII character it wants the terminal to display. You're relying on your terminal emulator to interpret those codes correctly.

Unfortunately, the ANSI color codes date back to when terminals and PC graphics cards and monitors could only display 8 or 16 colors (if that), so you can't use ANSI color codes for what you're trying to do.

So, short of building all the infrastructure yourself (terminal emulators that can do relative colors, a new color escape-code system for communicating relative colors to your emulators, and possibly the related terminfo/termcap and other terminal-related software infrastructure work to make sure scripts can reliably recognize that the user is using a terminal emulator that knows these new color tricks), and forcing your users to use it, you'll probably have to do without.

Comment: Ok, then my question still stands, but instead of every time I say bash, think "terminal." I guess I should start a new thread

Comment: @Mikhail No need to post a new question, because my answer still stands. No terminals support relative colors, so there's nothing you can do unless you write your own Terminal emulator and get it ported to and installed on lots of systems, and update those systems' terminfo and related infrastructure, and force your users to run your terminal software.

Answer (score 0):

Found this very detailed page on [interpreted styles and colors](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) by common terminals. For the original question, on emphasis there are a few tricks that can be done. Just keep in mind that this may not work on all terminals, as has been pointed out by Spiff, it's up to the terminal to interpret an escape sequence. From that page:

```
echo -e "Normal \e[1mBold"
```

[image]

```
echo -e "Normal \e[2mDim"
```

[image]

On my terminal I also tried `\e[9` which resulted in a <strike>strikethrough</strike> text.

Using styles like these is better than using colors because you'll never get an invisible combination, unless you intentionally use `\e[8`. If some style is ignored by the terminal you will simply see plain text.